# Create a function that outputs spending level based on money spent - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, defined

How do I create a function that says that for example if a person spends 100 dollars they are bronze, whereas if they spend between 100 dollars and 200 dollars they are silver?

I am trying to learn how to use user defined functions rather than loops, so would prefer no suggestions using loops.

Thanks

Comment: welcome to SO.  [Please read this to understand the MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Show what you have attempted, then come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: Not using loops is a strange request: using a function and using loops aren't mutually exclusive. Probably most functions I write have some sort of loop in them. But, I suggest that you try to implement something yourself, and report the *specific difficulties* you are experience, otherwise, this question is going to be too broad for stack-overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary which maps the different increment keys to a value. Then you just need to calculate which key your 'amount_spent' is closest to and choose the value from the dictionary which this corresponds to

```
def prestige_level(amount_spent):
    levels = {0: 'bronze', 
              100: 'silver', 
              200: 'gold'}

    key = min([x for x in levels if amount_spent >= x], key=lambda x: abs(x - amount_spent))
    return levels[key]


print(prestige_level(1))
>> bronze
print(prestige_level(100))
>> silver
print(prestige_level(101))
>> silver
print(prestige_level(199))
>> silver
print(prestige_level(200))
>> gold
print(prestige_level(201))
>> gold
print(prestige_level(1000))
>> gold
```

Comment: Um, what's the point of using a `dict` if *you always have to iterate over it?* Why not `if, elif, else`?

Comment: I tried to use if and elif in my iteration but it doesn't work... do you think I should share that code and that could help me?

Comment: Because the answer he's looking for is so simple it's not worth the effort to code. This however was a bit of a challenge, I enjoyed it and it's an answer to his question (plus its saved in my history for future reference)

Comment: @ErikaG if you want an answer on SO you should always share code. Otherwise you will be downvoted into oblivion

Answer (score 0):

What you'd likely want to use here is an If Statement with comparative operators.

You could make a python function to do this like so.

```
def findSpendingLevel(moneySpent):
  if (moneySpent <= 100):
    return 'bronze'

  if (moneySpent > 100 and moneySpent <= 200):
    return 'silver'

  if (moneySpent > 200 and moneySpent <= 300):
    return 'gold'

  if (moneySpent > 300):
    return 'diamond'
```

Would likely be good for your purposes. Notice how this works by taking in an *argument* which is the *moneySpent* variable, and comparing it to the boundaries of your money levels with **less-than-or-equal-to** (**<=**) and **greater-than** (**>**) comparative operators.

Comment: I tried something very similarly to this originally, and at the end I said else : level ' does not exist' and then I said return level, but it didn't work.

Comment: What was the code that you wrote? Can you share it in the question?